# ASP.NET MVC routing returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I am trying to get a URL for the following route:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
    null,
    "cinema",
    new
{
    Controller = "CinemaListings",
    Action = "ShowCinemaLandingPage",
    SiteArea = "CinemaTimes",
    MainLandingPage = true
});
```

I've tried the following methods to produce the URL:

```
<%:Url.Action("ShowCinemaLandingPage", "CinemaTimes", new { SiteArea = "CinemaTimes", MainLandingPage = true})%>
<%:Url.RouteUrl(new { Controller = "CinemaTimes", Action = "ShowCinemaLandingPage", SiteArea = "CinemaTimes", MainLandingPage = true })%>
```

I've also tried with only the controller and action names. I get null returned - what am I missing?

Comment: What 'type' is SiteArea? Is it a string parameter?  Can you show us the controller/action with parameters that this maps to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't this work?

```
<%:Url.Action("ShowCinemaLandingPage", "CinemaListings", new { SiteArea = "CinemaTimes", MainLandingPage = true })%>
```

It seems from your code that you've mixed up `SiteArea` with `Controller` values. So instead of providing controller name in `Url.Action`, you've provided `SiteArea` twice (as second parameter and as additional route value).

Comment: Argh! I'll give that a test a get back to you *walks away kicking himself*

Answer (score -1):

It is hard to understand your route. First of all, you have not given it name (passing null which I have experienced before causing problem) and then there is no place holder in there.

This cannot work without giving it a controller.

```
<%:Url.Action("ShowCinemaLandingPage", "CinemaTimes", new { SiteArea = "CinemaTimes", MainLandingPage = true})%>
```

Here you are passing controller name but since there is no controller name, no path will be matched.

So I would use - at bare minimum - this:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
    "GiveMeSomeNameWillYa?",
    "{Controller}/{Action}",
    new
{
    Controller = "CinemaListings",
    Action = "ShowCinemaLandingPage",
    SiteArea = "CinemaTimes",
    MainLandingPage = true
});
```

Comment: The route does work for incoming requests. Any requests to /cinema will be handled by the `ShowCinemaLandingPage` on the `CinemaListings` controller. I need to maintain this behaviour. I've tried adding the route name but this had no effect.

Comment: -1 Route name is completely optional. The URL template doesn't require controller and action tokens, if these are provided with default values.